# Java Spring How to convert MultipartFile to File and save to ArrayList?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, file, spring-mvc

I receive a MultipartFile from the Frontend part and want to convert it into a File and then save it into an ArrayList for later use. How can I do it?

```
private ArrayList<File> uploadedFiles = new ArrayList<>();

    @PostMapping("/uploadFiles")
    public ResponseEntity<String> handleFileUpload(@RequestParam("files") List<MultipartFile> files) {
        for (MultipartFile file : files) {
            try {
                File newFile = convertMultiPartToFile(file);
                uploadedFiles.add(newFile);


            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return ResponseEntity.status(500).body("Failed to upload files");
            }
        }
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Files uploaded successfully");
    }
```

I tried to convert the file using this method but when checking for existence I get False.

```
private File convertMultiPartToFile(MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
        File convFile = new File(file.getOriginalFilename());
        file.transferTo(convFile);
        return convFile;
    }
```

Comment: What does this transfer-to method do?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply return the converted file and it will do the desired work

`private File convertMultiPartToFile(MultipartFile file) throws IOException { return new File(file.getOriginalFilename()); }`